# Android build cycle with eclipse and ant

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ant, build

First of all, **my goal**:
On running the android application I want to create a new String with the current date/time to display in the application and/or store in the strings.xml.
I tried to get into the build and run process with android, eclipse and ant.

**What I did so far:**

I did `android update project --target --path`, I tried eclipse -> export -> ant build files,
I somehow managed to execute "ant" on cmd with the "BUILD SUCCESSFUL" result (but it didn't start the application because building and running is different as I learned later), I searched my android sdk for the android_rules.xml but couldn't find it.

But my real struggle is **understanding** the build and run cycle of an Android project, additionally with ant.

Can someone please help me with this? I haven't found anything understandable for basics.
It would be nice to get an approach for my problem with the string on build.

Zuop